# Can't access any of my website pages other than homepage

Tags: apache

I have implemented a website based on Apache infra.
I didn't make any modifications to the httpd file, so you can assume it is mostly default define.
The problem is that when browsing directly to any page which isn't the homepage, I'm getting this message:

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

It looks to me that this message comes from Apache itself. Will appreciate any advice how to fix it.

This is how my httpd directory section define:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

I don't have `.htaccess` file.

I tried to check if the message comes from Apache or not. Looks to me that the Apache is blocking direct browsing to pages in the website.
BTW, when browsing the website via the homepage, all working well. It is just when I try to browse directly to any page in the website,
for example:
When browsing: https://www.forexample.com - all goes well, and if I'm using the link to "contact us" I'm getting the contact up page.

But, when trying directly: https://www.forexample.com/contact - I'm getting the "not found" message.